# What is the distribution for maximum difference of pigeon-holing

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have N balls, and M baskets. N>>M. For each ball, I randomly (uniform distribution) pick a basket and throw it in. I am interested in finding the maximum difference of ball numbers in all the baskets.

1, Is there a known distribution of the maximum difference for this problem?

2, If not, is there any analytical solution?

3, Even if question 2 has a solution, I believe it can be very complicated, and not easily computable. Is there any easily computable approximation or bound on this?

BTW, this is not a homework problem. It is encountered in a real-world industry problem.

Thank you very much!